# Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, pagination

How to make the previous button disabled before clicking on the 1 or next button. after clicking on the next button it should be enabled. and also when I select 1 ,2 or 3 the number field should be selected.

```
   <nav >
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item ">
                <span class="page-link" (click)="getAllBudgetHead('prev')" >Previous</span>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item " aria-current="page" (click)="getAllBudgetHead(1)">
                <span class="page-link">1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" (click)="getAllBudgetHead(2)" >2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" (click)="getAllBudgetHead(3)" >3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" (click)="getAllBudgetHead(4)" >4</a></li>

            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" (click)="getAllBudgetHead('next')">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Ts file

```
 p: number = 1;

getAllBudgetHead(pageNo) {
    if(pageNo=='prev' ){
      this.p=this.p-1
    }else if(pageNo=='next'){
      this.p=this.p+1
    }else{
      this.p=pageNo
    }
    this.user.getBudget(this.p).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.budgetData = res.data.budgetHeadPageDtoList;
      console.log(this.budgetData);

    })

  }
```

I simply hardcoded the values

Comment: This is usually done from backend and for those sites which have database, and bootstrap has its inbuilt classes `active` and `disabled`.

Comment: Can't we do that here? because I simply hardcoded the values of the backend for now.

Comment: You can do that, but it is handled through backend.

Comment: okay how to do that here

Answer (score 0):

In general you should to have two variables: `pageIndex` and `pageLength` (this it's necesary you get from your dbs). I like the pageIndex goes from 0 to pageLength-1, but if you want to gageIndex go from 1 to pageLength, you can do some similar to:

```
<ul class="pagination">
     <!--the prev button-->
     <li class="page-item ">
          <a class="page-link" 
             [class.disabled]="pageIndex<=1" 
             (click)="pageIndex>1 && getAllBudgetHead('prev')">
                 Previous
          </a>
     </li>
     <!--the "pages" buttons-->
     <li *ngFor="let page of ".".repeat(pageLength);let i=index"
        class="page-item " aria-current="page"> 
        <a class="page-link" (click)="getAllBudgetHead(i+1)">
                {{i+1}}
        </a>
     </li>
     <!--the next button-->
     <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             [class.disabled]="pageIndex>=pageLength"  
             (click)="pageIndex>=pageLength && getAllBudgetHead('next')">
              Next
          </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

See the use of `(click)="condition && function()"`. This makes that the function is not executed if condition=false

See also that a `<a>` always response to click event. A `button` can be disabled but not an `<a>`